# Does DataGridViewTextBoxColumn has text changed event handler?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need help with my datagridview
all the columns are read only except Quantity Column. The user can input any quantity value and displays the result of (Price * Quantity) to the Subtotal Column automatically

[image: Click here to see example]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Asking a clear question will make it easier to help you. Including the work that you've done until now and sharing  the error if there is any is very important. please read this article to make sure that you get a good answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If the subtotal column is defined with an Expression, you dont have to worry about it

Comment: you __could__ grab the TextBox in the EditControlShowing event and add an TextChanged event handler. But it hardly makes sense for every keystroke, does it? Better look into the DGV.CellEndEdit or CellValueChanged events..

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is late but try and add this into your code:

```
Private Sub dg1_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dg1.CellValueChanged
    Try
        dg1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
        If e.ColumnIndex = 9 Then 'columindex for your QUANTITY. 9 is just a sample
            dg1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
            dg1.CurrentRow.Cells("SubTotal").Value = (VAL(dgSalesOrderLine.CurrentRow.Cells("SalesOrderAmount").Value) * VAL(dgSalesOrderLine.CurrentRow.Cells("SalesOrderQuantity").Value))
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub dg1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dg1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
    dg1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
End Sub
```